# Delete all data in tables except system versioned (history) tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to delete all data in all tables except system versioned (because we can't). This is part of an integration test that clears data before running each test.

The following statement returns `1` for history tables (the ones that we cannot execute `delete from` on them.

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('table_name'), 'TableTemporalType')
```

So my attempt was as follows:

```
-- Remove check constraints
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
-- Delete data
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''?''), ''TableTemporalType'') != 1 DELETE FROM ?'
-- Restore check constraints
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
```

However, I am still getting the error:

`Cannot delete rows from a temporal history table 'dbo.table_name'.`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: You are going to struggle with this idea aside from the temporal tables. Things like foreign keys are going to cause you all sorts of fun. Seems like it would be easier to script out the tables, then drop the tables and recreate them.

Comment: @SeanLange I am already removing all constraints checks with `EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'` prior to deletion then restoring them after. Question updated.

Comment: I would recommend not using that sp_MSforeachtable for anything. It is a cursor behind the scenes. Why not just use sys.tables to generate a long dynamic sql string and execute it?

Comment: @SeanLange This is part of an integration test run that clears all data before executing each test so this is probably the easier solution for my use-case

Comment: I would think using a dynamic string you can control would be easier. And it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by generating some dynamic sql using sys.tables. Something like this should be pretty close to what you are trying to do.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'delete ' + name + ';'
from sys.tables
where temporal_type = 0

select @sql
--uncomment the line below when you are ready to blow away all your data
--exec sp_executesql @sql
```